# Google geocoder returns wrong coordinates for address

Tags: javascript, google-maps, geocoding

I plot locations of real estate on a map. The address listed below is mapped incorrectly because it is a new build and I assume the street and everything is a new build, which is the reason Google can't find it in it's database.

What I want to happen is Google return "GeocoderStatus.ZERO_RESULTS" and not just pick a location with a related name and give me those coords.

The address I'm plotting is:

14018 Lonecreek Ave
Orlando, Florida 32828

If you submit the request via http, you get the same results i get through the API, see this link: http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=140

You'll see it comes back with "Lone Hill Drive" which is incorrect location. How can I tell Google return ZERO_RESULTS status in this instance?

Comment: https://support.google.com/maps/answer/162873?hl=en

Comment: When you get the results you can loop through components to see if the type is street?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Google's geocoding process isn't perfect (none are.)

What you can check for is the result's `geometry.location_type` property and test if it's value is `"APPROXIMATE"` to see if you can trust the returned lat/lng. Read more in the [Documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/).

If it's way off you can [report it](https://support.google.com/maps/answer/162873?hl=en) directly to google.

Comment: This worked, I also needed to check for "GEOMETRIC_CENTER". Thanks for the solution.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. OP's example geocoding request returns an incorrect address but with a location_type of geometric_center. Presumably Google considers this an accurate result.

Comment: @Moob geometric_center also is an approximate result

Answer (score 3):

You can use the API's [Component Filtering](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#ComponentFiltering) to filter the results by a specific postcode. In such cases a non-exact match will have `location_type` of `"APPROXIMATE"` rather than the `"GEOMETRIC_CENTER"` you were seeing before.

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=[address]&components=postal_code:[postcode]&sensor=false
```

Here's your geocoding request [WITH component filtering](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=14018+Lonecreek+Ave+Orlando+Florida+32828&components=postal_code:32828&sensor=false) 
and [WITHOUT component filtering](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=14018+Lonecreek+Ave+Orlando+Florida+32828&sensor=false)